# SQL Выборка по диапазону дат в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Делаю графики по заявкам (самописная CRM на Laravel & Angular), сам график реализую с помощью chart js, все отлично работает но вот по тз нужно подсчитывать заявки по произвольному диапазону дат, на пример с 2018-01-01 по 2018-03-01, подскажите как написать сам запрос в БД, ибо в документации Laravel не нашел ничего. Версия Laravel  5.5.

```
   $statuses = DB::table('order_statuses')->get(); 
    $statuses = json_decode($statuses);

    $status_names = [];
    $status_colors = [];
    $status_length = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($statuses); $i++) {
        $status_names[] .= $statuses[$i] -> status_name;
        $status_colors[] .= $statuses[$i] -> status_color;
    };
    $statuses = [];
    $statuses['status_names'] = $status_names;
    $statuses['status_colors'] = $status_colors;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($status_names); $i++) {
        $orders =  DB::table('orders')->where('status', $status_names[$i])->get();
        $status_length[] .= count($orders);
    }
    $statuses['status_value'] = $status_length;
    return $statuses;
```

Comment: Есть пример того, что уже попытался сделать для выборки?

Comment: Могу показать то что работает, но там много лишнего, основное - `for($i = 0; $i < count($status_names); $i++) {
            $orders =  DB::table('orders')->where('status', $status_names[$i])->get();
            $status_length[] .= count($orders);
        }
        $statuses['status_value'] = $status_length;
        return $statuses;` $status_names - список со статусами, получаю в другом запросе

Comment: я думаю могу тебе подсказать, но печатать сейчас влом. Могу по скайпу, как раз уточняющие вопросы смогу задать

Comment: Скайпа нет( Телеграм?

Comment: я хотел, чтобы ты мне экран с кодом показал, есть ряд вопросов по структуре бд и контроллеру. В телеграме у меня звонки нестабильные (РКН старается, гад)

Comment: это можно сказать весь контроллер, структуру бд могу показать, там ничего особенного, поле дата с обычным форматом date

Comment: Ну пиши в телеграм @maxkut со скринами (или может есть репозиторий), Есть ли модели `Order` и `OrderStatus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть две даты в переменных, то условие в Ларавеловском билдере можно записать так:

```
->whereBetween('orderDate', [date('Y-m-d',$date1), date('Y-m-d',$date2)])
```

Если в будущем никак не получится записать запрос через ларавеловский билдер - помни, что Лара оставила тебе возможность написать запрос частично или полностью текстом SQL, используя DB::raw()